# migrate from ScrollView to FlatList

Tags: react-native

I have a large list of items fetched from a server, it works fine but the problem that is my ScrollView take a long time to render items, after reading react-native Documentations I fund that I have to use "FlatList" or "SectionList" instead of ScrollView, how can I refactor this code to use FlatList?

thanks

```
import React from 'react';
import {ScrollView, View, Text, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import ProductItem from 'src/containers/ProductItem';
import {padding} from 'src/components/config/spacing';

const WIDTH_SCREEN = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const Carousel = ({
  data,
  width,
  height,
  widthView,
  col,
  box,
  navigationType
}) => {
  const separator = padding.base;
  const paddingEnd = box ? padding.large: 0;
  const column = col > 0 ? col : 1.5;
  const widthImage = widthView/column;
  const heightImage =(widthImage * height)/width;

  return (
    <ScrollView
      horizontal
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      style={{
        marginHorizontal: -separator/2,
      }}
    >
      {data.map((item, index) => (
        <View
          key={item.id}
          style={{
            marginLeft: separator/2,
            marginRight: index === data.length - 1 ? separator/2 + paddingEnd: separator/2,
          }}
        >
          <ProductItem
            item={item}
            width={widthImage}
            height={heightImage}
            navigationType={navigationType}
          />
        </View>
      ))}
    </ScrollView>
  )
};

Carousel.defaultProps = {
  data: [],
  width: 204,
  height: 257,
  widthView: WIDTH_SCREEN,
  col: 1.5,
  box: false,
};
export default Carousel;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your front-end code looks ok to me. The best method is to go for pagination at your backend and fetch data as small patches. Then you can render piece by piece, saying 5 items at a time. This way you can avoid delay.